# Find derivative of a complicated fraction

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $n> 1$ be an integer and let $x_1,\ldots,x_n$  be positive real numbers, all between $0$ and $1$. Is it possible to find the derivative of it so I know if it is increasing wrt $x_i$?
$$
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}{1-\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1-x_i)}\
$$
I thought about expanding it to $$
\frac{x_1+x_2+...x_i}{1-(1-x_1)(1-x_2)...(1-x_i)}\
$$

Comment: What have you tried? Have you studied partial derivatives yet?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let
$$A=\sum_{j\neq i}x_j$$
$$B=\prod_{j\neq i}(1-x_j)$$